# Check if a specific string exists between two strings

Tags: regex, pcre

String:

`category_a:1280,1288,1255,1355,1755|category_b:1355,1279,78|category_c:1279,383,593,488`

I want to know how to check the existence of a specific number up to the next `|`. For example, I want to check whether `category_b` contain the number `1279`. I have tried

`/(category_b:)(.*)(\b(1279)\b)(|)/`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/tH3aK4/2)

but it matches all the way to the `category_c`.

I don't know how to put the `?` to make it stop at the next occurrence of "|" after the first match `1279` in `category_b` so it won't proceed to `category_c`.

The regex engine the script is using is PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/(category_b:)(.*?)(\b(1279)\b)/
```

You need to change the * to a *? which makes it reluctant instead of greedy.  A greedy quantifier will "eat" as much as it can and still make a match (thus it goes past the next category designator).  A reluctant quantifier will "eat" as little as possible and still make a match (thus it will avoid the next category unless it has to go into it).

However, this may still have a few problems.  I would further try:

```
/(category_b:)([0-9,]*?)(\b(1279)\b)/
```

which will not allow that string after the category_b to have anything BUT numbers and commas.  This would prevent a match on

```
category_a:1280,1288,1255,1355,1755|category_b:1355,1278,78|category_c:1279,383,593,488
```

Comment: Why use `(|)` at all? `[0-9,]*?` can be replaced with `[^|]*` if there can be more than just digits and a comma before the required `1279`.

Comment: You are right about the `(|)`.  I have edited to remove it.  I copied that from the OP's example, and it didn't strike me that it was useless until I saw your comment.  I suspect that the OP was trying to mark it as a deliminator which would actually require `\|`, but that would cause it to fail anyways.  In the OP's example, only comma separated digits appear, so I used the character class with those to limit the possible matches as much as possible.